# how to add a block in magenot preview view page

Tags: view, product, magento-1.9

i am using a market place i want to show vendor information on product view page on right side , this is the market place support team said to follow but its not clear can you help me , 
show vendor detail on product view page. You can preprare your phtml file in which you need to get vendor id from product information by first loading product model like this:

Comment: `$_product = $this->getProduct(); 
$vproduct = Mage::getModel("csmarketplace/vproducts"); 
and from it take out 'Vendor Id' like this-:
$vid = (int) $vproduct->getVendorIdByProduct($_product);

Comment: After getting vendor ID you can load vendor model like this-> 
$vendor = Mage::getModel("csmarketplace/vendor")->load($vid);
and from this you can get all vendor information you need. You can add link for the vendor review profile on this phtml.Call this phtml from your block and you can see vendor information on product view page.`